# Given linear operator $A: R^3 \to R^3$, $\forall x \in R^3: (Ax, x)=0$, prove that A is skew-symmetric operator.

Tags: linear-algebra, skew-symmetric-matrices

Given linear operator $A: R^3 \to R^3$, $\forall x \in R^3: (Ax, x)=0$, prove that A is skew-symmetric operator.
I came up with a solution like: if $(Ax, x) = 0 \implies (x, A^{T}x)=(A^{T}x, x)=0 \implies (Ax, x) + (A^{T}x, x)= 0 = ((A+A^{T})x,x)=0 \ \forall x$ then $A+A^{T}=0$, but I'm not sure that last implication is correct.

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: If the last step were correct, then you'd essentially be saying in the original problem you must have $A = 0$.  But that isn't true in general: for example if $A = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to need to make more direct use of $(A x, x) = 0$. Specifically, consider that the $(i,j)^{\text{th}}$ element of $A$ (call it $a_{i, j}$) can be found by $$a_{i, j} = (A e_j, e_i)$$

We can conclude that $A$ is skew symmetric if we can show $a_{i, j} = - a_{j, i}$ for all $i, j$. To take advantage of the hypothesis, let's try using $x = e_i + e_j$:
$$
0 = (Ax, x) = (A(e_i + e_j), e_i + e_j) = (Ae_i, e_i) + (Ae_i, e_j) + (Ae_j, e_i) + (Ae_j, e_j)
$$

Of course, we already know that $(Ae_i, e_i) = (Ae_j, e_j) = 0$ by hypothesis. Thus we have
$$
(Ae_i, e_j) + (Ae_j, e_i) = a_{j, i} + a_{i, j} = 0
$$

which is what we wanted to show.